# How do I detect movement direction based on deltas and forward rotation?

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, game-development, quaternions, calculus

I need to determine if an object/player is moving left or right (using math, this isn't necessarily a coding question). I'm working with a UGC game system that provides no events for movement and no key bindings.

What I can do is detect movement between frames.

A player can move forward, backward, and then strafe left and right. The forward, backward detection was easy to build. I'm struggling to separate strafe movement direction with the data at hand.

How to detect if moving left or right instead of forward or back. The deltas are all arbitrary numbers since the player can look in any direction with any global coordinates.

Data I have available:

- Local forward rotation
- Local right rotation
- Look location (vector3 of the starting point of where the player is "looking"
- Look rotation
- Deltas between frames
- Current player position (Global X,Y,Z coordinates)

I feel like there is some piece of math I'm missing using the data I have.

My code for detecting forward movement overrides any ability to check for strafe left or strafe right (ie it always detects as moving forward or moving backward, even though we are actually strafing)

```
IsMovingForward(strafeData: []vector2, threshold: float, lookLocation: vector2)<transacts>:logic=
        for (i := 1..strafeData.Length - 1):
            if:
                var currentY: float = strafeData[i].Y
                var previousY: float = strafeData[i - 1].Y
                var movementDirection: vector2 = lookLocation - strafeData[i]
            then:
                if ((currentY < previousY - threshold) and DotProduct(movementDirection,vector2{X := 0.0, Y := 1.0}) > 0.0):
                    return true
  
    
        return false
```

Strafe Left example:

```
IsStrafingRight(strafeData: []vector2, threshold: float, lookLocation: vector2)<transacts>: logic =
        for (i := 1..strafeData.Length - 1):
            if:
                var currentX: float = strafeData[i].X
                var previousX: float = strafeData[i - 1].X
                var movementDirection: vector2 = lookLocation - strafeData[i]
            then:
                if ((currentX > previousX + threshold) and DotProduct(movementDirection,vector2{X := 1.0, Y := 0.0}) > 0.0):
                    return true
        
        return false
```

And here are some data printouts:

```
Here is some data when the character is actually moving forward:

Look Location X: 698.000000, Look Location Y: -934.000000, Position X: 854.902138, Position Y: -1132.921194
Look Location X: 918.000000, Look Location Y: -1134.000000, Position X: 1074.329936, Position Y: -1332.192619
Look Location X: 1139.000000, Look Location Y: -1334.000000, Position X: 1293.633482, Position Y: -1531.351207


Here is some data when the character is actually moving backward:

Look Location X: -1504.000000, Look Location Y: 358.000000, Position X: -1293.541331, Position Y: 248.787424
Look Location X: -1642.000000, Look Location Y: 401.000000, Position X: -1432.408226, Position Y: 291.884073
Look Location X: -1781.000000, Look Location Y: 444.000000, Position X: -1570.835936, Position Y: 334.804371


Here is some data when the character is actually strafing left:

Look Location X: -820.000000, Look Location Y: -509.000000, Position X: -605.316399, Position Y: -636.171886
Look Location X: -870.000000, Look Location Y: -680.000000, Position X: -652.496627, Position Y: -797.602712
Look Location X: -920.000000, Look Location Y: -852.000000, Position X: -702.114209, Position Y: -967.373138


Here is some data when the character is actually strafing right:

Look Location X: -231.000000, Look Location Y: 1050.000000, Position X: -37.965773, Position Y: 927.290377
Look Location X: -149.000000, Look Location Y: 1208.000000, Position X: 40.164043, Position Y: 1079.690529
Look Location X: -69.000000, Look Location Y: 1365.000000, Position X: 116.869361, Position Y: 1229.334067
```